# NodeJS socket.io HTTPS, multiple connection instead of one

Tags: node.js, https, websocket, socket.io

I use the same code than the socket.io simple chat example https://github.com/socketio/chat-example but i use an https server instead of http (which work fine).

When I reached the url, instead of building one web socket connection as expected, it creates lot of them and I dont understand why? It seems to come from HTTPS but I don t understand the reason.

[image: console - requests]

here is my code if you want to take a look at it:
app.js
https://github.com/maximeSurmontGH/TP_dev_Web/blob/master/TP9%20Maxime%20SURMONT/app.js

index.html
https://github.com/maximeSurmontGH/TP_dev_Web/blob/master/TP9%20Maxime%20SURMONT/index.html

Comment: These are not websocket connections. This is xhr polling fallback. I'm not sure why socket.io decided it cannot use websockets over https.

Comment: Those aren't multiple connections. Websockets connect over a handshake and send heartbeats to maintain the connection (a websocket is just a HTTP protocol with an upgrade header passed in)

Comment: So I won't be able to use socket.io with https protocol?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the same version of socket.io on both client and server.  There are cases where mismatched versions prevent socket.io from ever establishing a persistent webSocket connection and it just uses polling forever.  Also, what client are these connections coming from?  FYI, when you load the client socket.io from a CDN, it's really easy to get a version mismatch.  If you load it from your socket.io server itself, you never get a version mismatch.

Comment: I changed to get the same version but i have no changement. And I m using chrome here.